# NULL and NOT NULL in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql. thanks for the answer in advance.

NULL is used for fields in which non value CAN be inserted such as 'Having a driving licence?' ?

Comment: Uhmm...what? I think you would rather want to use a tinyint or bool for a field such as "Having a drivers license".

Answer (score 3):

A `NULL` is typically used to show that the value is not known, or that there is no value for that field.

If you asked someone if they had a driver's license, they might say yes (`TRUE`) or no (`FALSE`). But if you didn't ask them yet, or they didn't answer the question, then you don't know (`NULL`).

Quite often you want to disallow a column from containing `NULL`. This can be done by declaring the column as `NOT NULL`.

Usage of `NULL` is a very controversial topic. In the original definition of normal forms for databases, having a nullable column meant that your design was not in [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). More recent definitions typically relax this constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's right. Some [further reading](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html).

Edit: Since the wording of your question is a little vague, this is my interpretation of the question: You want to know the semantics of NULL vs NOT NULL in a column definition. In your example, "has driving license", it seems that NULL is a reasonable value, say, if the question hasn't been answered, so you wish to allow NULL. In this case, yes, use NULL (although it's implied, so it's enough not to use NOT NULL).